# What are some hosting providers that are PHP 7 Ready?

Tags: web-hosting, php

I am creating a list of all providers that are supporting PHP from ages and currently migrated to PHP 7. So the simple question is, how many of the hosting providers we have onboard that are providing PHP 7 with full support?

Comment: Questions asking for hosting providers that meet certain requirements are marked as a duplicate of the linked catch-all question since they often result in spam or self-promotional answers. [Open-ended](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), polling questions are also considered off-topic here.

Comment: @dan I think you didn't understand my question seriously (-_-) I'm creating a list of web hosting providers who are offering PHP 7, This is not similar to the question you linked. And it is not even answering my question because I can't even find "PHP7" or "PHP 7" keyword in the How to find web hosting that meets my requirements? link. So please understand what others are asking then you may comment below or answer. This is totally different from what you are saying.

Comment: I understood what you were asking. Please refer to the top of that question:  `This is a "catch-all" question...All future questions pertaining to finding web hosting should be closed as a duplicate of this question. For more information about this policy please see this meta question.` Also, please note that [recommendations for sites and resources](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here, which is why we use the above catch-all question.